# Windows api documentation

Tags: java, windows

Где можно найти документацию для создания  приложений на java под винду?
Пересмотрел много источников. Но не нашел ничего толкового.

Comment: Что значит "нативных приложений на java под винду"? Java кросс-платформенна.

Comment: *обычных программ*

Comment: Если вы под обычными программами понимаете десктопные приложения под винду, то в Java полно GUI фреймворков для этого: AWT, Swing, SWT, JavaFX. Посмотрите JavaFX, это самый последний из фреймворков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) найдете всю необходимую информацию по созданию ГПИ с помощью Swing и JavaFX. Рекомендую использовать JavaFX. А вообще-то Java кроссплатформенный язык и можно писать под "что угодно".